# How to UT OptionParser()?

Tags: python, unit-testing

How can I unittest this code snippet?

```
def parse_arguments():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--debug",
                  action="store_true",
                  default=False)
    parser.add_option("--auto",
                  action="store_true",
                  default=False)

    (params, args) = parser.parse_args()

    return params
```

I tried this for example:

```
class testParseArguments(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.parser = parse_arguments()
        sys.argv.append(['--auto'])

    def test_something(self):
        parsed = self.parser.parse()
        self.assertTrue(parsed.auto)
        self.assertFalse(parsed.debug)
```

I tried to find some example with google but I did not find anything.
I am looking for advice, thanks.

Comment: It might help if you add a bit more detail to your question. Are you looking for advice on how to use the unittest framework or how best to mock the functionality within the code? What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for advice. I am trying to write UT for every function, but I can not write to this one. Question updated!